# Swift: ArraySlice<Array<String>> to [[String]]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of type `[[String]]` and I am trying to move first 4 elements from the array to another array.

For example:

```
var arr1: [[String]] = [["1", "2", "3"], ["2", "3", "4"], ["3", "4", "5"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["2", "3", "4"], ["3", "4", "5"]]
var arr2: [[String]] = arr1[0...3]
```

But I am getting error saying that `Cannot convert value of type 'Array<[String]>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Array<String>>') to specified type '[[String]]'`

My required output is `arr1` contains `[["2", "3", "4"], ["3", "4", "5"]]` and `arr2` contains `[["1", "2", "3"], ["2", "3", "4"], ["3", "4", "5"], ["1", "2", "3"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to (re)create an `Array` from the slice

```
let arr2 = Array(arr1[0...3])
```

Side note: It's not necessary to annotate types the compiler can infer.
In this case you could proceed without creating an array if the next step accepts a slice.

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the array

```
var arr2: [[String]] = [[String]]()
```

Then you can add elements to your array using 'append'

```
arr2.append(contentsOf: arr1[0...3])
```